# How to retrieve a specific childnode from a JSON in React Native

Tags: react-native

This is a function to display the name and temperature from a specific location from a weather API.
I am stuck because I can't print out any childnode from my JSON.

From searching the web this is how I've thought it's suppose to be:
`Temperatur: {this.state.data.main.temp}` but it's giving me an error-message.
`TypeError:undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.data.main.temp')`

How should I write to be able to get a childnode from my JSON?

```
class Weather extends Component {
    state = {
       data: ''
    }
    componentDidMount = () => {
       fetch('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=2702976&APPID=d256f5dfa347ef700fee86a5442d918d',
        {
          method: 'GET'
       })
       .then((response) => response.json())
       .then((responseJson) => {
          console.log(responseJson);

          this.setState({
             data: responseJson
          })
       })
       .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
       });
    }
    render() {
       return (
            <View style={{flex:1, alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center'}}>
             <Text>
                Ort: {this.state.data.name} **//This works**
                {'\n'}
                Temperatur: {this.state.data.main.temp} C **//This doesn't work.**
             </Text>
          </View>
       )
    }
 }
 export default Weather
```

This is the JSON I'm getting from the API.

```
 {
  "coord": {
    "lon": 14.5,
    "lat": 57.5
  },
  "weather": [
    {
      "id": 800,
      "main": "Clear",
      "description": "clear sky",
      "icon": "01d"
    }
  ],
  "base": "stations",
  "main": {
    "temp": 296.23,
    "pressure": 1017,
    "humidity": 37,
    "temp_min": 295.15,
    "temp_max": 297.15
  },
  "visibility": 10000,
  "wind": {
    "speed": 2.6,
    "deg": 30
  },
  "clouds": {
    "all": 0
  },
  "dt": 1529931000,
  "sys": {
    "type": 1,
    "id": 5385,
    "message": 0.0037,
    "country": "SE",
    "sunrise": 1529892265,
    "sunset": 1529957090
  },
  "id": 2702976,
  "name": "Jönköpings Län",
  "cod": 200
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line as below

```
Temperatur: {this.state.data.main && this.state.data.main.temp}
```

Reason for not working:
  You have received the api response only in `componentDidMount`. Before that method is called `render` will be called once. So before you get data, you have set your initial state as `data: ''` which is a string and you can't access `this.state.data.main` on a string.

Reason for `Ort: {this.state.data.name}` is working because it would translate as `Ort: {undefined}`. React will skip `undefined` values and dont render anything for them.

**Conclusion**:
 The above change will work anyhow I strongly recommend you to modify the constructor as to replicate the initial state same as the data you get.

Comment: Thanks, that works! 
But I'm curious about 'Ort'. The line `Ort: this.state.data.name`is previewing the correct location that is from the JSON. It doesn't give me any error.

Comment: It will not render the name on the first call of `render` which is before 'componentDidMount'. You cant see the difference because you had the error before, which actually stopped you from seeing empty space after `Ort:`.
For checking, You can comment out the api fetch in `componentDidMount` and look at the render. It will display an empty space

Comment: Cool, thanks alot for the lesson. I did not know that. 
I've thought that as long as you use `this.setState` the state is able to be called from anywhere.